# Android Studio: adding new methods in ListFragment not working

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on Fragments and communication between them, but I encountered something weird. I have my own ListFragment class:

```
//all necessary imports and packages

public class ListFragment extends android.app.ListFragment implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ArrayList items;

public ArrayList getItems(){
    return items;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflanter, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    View view = inflanter.inflate(R.layout.fragments, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = null;
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View vview, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

As you can see, it's all standard class for ListFragments, but I added one method: **getItems()**. Nothing unusual. But whenever I try to cast this method: it's not working. I mean, it is not even detected. Example:

```
//normal method somewhere in MainActivity; this method is working great
 @Override
public void sendButtonClicked() {

    ListFragment fragment = (ListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(com.ja.testofallthing.R.id.headlines_fragment);
    ArrayList list = fragment.getItems();
    fragment.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));

}
```

Looks okay, but I still get the "Cannot resolve method" error: 
[image: "Cannot resolve method" error]
So, what is wrong? When I try to add new method in other Fragments - it works great. But when I try in ListFragment - nope. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Is your import right? You must import your custom `ListFragment` not `android.app.ListFragment`

Comment: @EduardoHerzer you're absolutely right, I changed the import and everything works great. Note for me: use special, unique names for custom classes to avoid such mistakes xD If you write a normal answer containing this tip, I will mark this as a correct solution if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import your custom `ListFragment` not `android.app.ListFragment`

I would advise not to use same class names that android. So you avoid this problems.